# Loading of selected tabs containing a Webview

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview, android-viewpager

I have 3 categories of Fragments within Viewpager, each containing 3 or 4 tabs. Every tab has a Webview with different url. When I start the activty to load the fragments, the webviews of every fragment are loading simultaneously and takes much time. I want to load the present fragment which contains 4 tabs and when changed to other fragment, load the 4 tabs which the fragment has. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Android built-in `ViewPager` can not load only one page at a time, it Load at least two pages ahead of time, so the user can swipe between them.

Here is a [CustomViewPager](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3utJsLFk7yKOS1vclV0YTR1NTA/view)

download it and place the class in your project, use like below:

```
CustomViewPager mViewPager;
mViewPager = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.swipePager);
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
```

in xml:

```
 <com.yourpackagename.CustomViewPager 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swipePager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: Will it load the fragment when I go to second page in Viewpager?